# ¿Puedo concatenar varias filas de MySQL en un campo?

Tags: mysql, sql, concat, group-concat

Usando MySQL, puedo hacer algo como:

```
SELECT hobbies FROM peoples_hobbies WHERE person_id = 5;
```

**Mi salida :**

```
shopping
fishing
coding
```

pero en cambio solo quiero 1 fila, 1 columna:

**Rendimiento esperado :**

```
shopping, fishing, coding
```

El motivo es que estoy seleccionando varios valores de varias tablas y, después de todas las uniones, tengo muchas más filas de las que me gustaría.

Busqué una función en [MySQL Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) y no parece que las funciones CONCATo CONCAT_WS acepten conjuntos de resultados.

**Traducido de :** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field

**Nota :** Lo he traducido del sitio original porque me parece interesante y además hay personas que no entiende el ingles y con esto podemos ayudarle.

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba así:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(hobbies SEPARATOR ', ')
  FROM peoples_hobbies
  WHERE person_id = 5;
```

La función `GROUP_CONCAT()` hace precisamente lo que necesitas: totaliza todos los datos en un único resultado y por defecto los separa por comas. Con `SEPARATOR` puedes añadir el espacio que te falta.

También lo puedes combinar con un `GROUP BY` como cualquier función de totales.

Comment: Muchas gracias Amigo

Comment: una pregunta se puede traducir pregunta de un sitio a otro no?

Comment: Ah, ya me parecía raro que tuvieras esa duda con todo lo que habías investigado... :) Igual a alguien le sirve, pero yo creo que mejor es que publiques dudas que realmente te surjan a ti, que seguro que son más interesantes que las traducidas...

Comment: Vale muchas gracias

Comment: ¡No olvides explicar qué hace `GROUP_CONCAT`!